# Where to keep JS and HTML files using both Thymeleaf and AngularJS?

Tags: java, html, angularjs, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am starting to build a Spring Boot web application on top of the Dave Syer's example [here](https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/12/spring-and-angular-js-a-secure-single-page-application). He uses plain html files with AngularJS, that's why he has a file structure like this:

[image]

Everything is under static folder. Since the example application is really small, he has created a folder for each page (which i will definitely change in the future).

But i also want to use Thymeleaf and it uses the templates folder as default, as the spring boot defines this default property:

```
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
```

Now i do not know if i simply should overwrite that prefix property in my application.yml to sth like *spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/static*, or create a template folder and move all my html files in that folder, leaving just the JS files in static. What is the best way of having this combination?